# Habilitar/Deshabilitar checkbox segun el value de un input

Tags: javascript, html

necesito que segun el value de un input, se desactiven o habiliten checkboxs.

Ejemplo: En un campo input tipo text tengo el value el numero de hijos. Si en el input tengo 1 como valor, que se habilite el primer checkbox y se deshabiliten los demás.

Trate de hacerlo asi, pero no se ejecuta y da error en consola, por favor

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('input[name=hijos]').var() === 1) {
       $('input[name=1]').prop('disabled', false);
       $('input[name=2]').prop('disabled', true);
       $('input[name=3]').prop('disabled', true);

    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <label for="hijos">N° Hijos</label>
  <input type="text" name="hijos" value="1" disabled> <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="1" disabled>Valor 1 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="2" disabled>Valor 2 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="3" disabled>Valor 3 <br>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varios errores.  Primero, el valor del input es un string, por lo que tienes que convertir a entero para comparar o simplemente usar el operador `==`.  Segundo, tienes un typo en el if.  `var()` deberia ser `val()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('input[name="hijos"]').val() == 1) {
       $('input[name="1"]').prop('disabled', false);
       $('input[name="2"]').prop('disabled', true);
       $('input[name="3"]').prop('disabled', true);

    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <label for="hijos">N° Hijos</label>
  <input type="text" name="hijos" value="1" disabled> <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="1" disabled>Valor 1 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="2" disabled>Valor 2 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="3" disabled>Valor 3 <br>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Justo estaba editando la respuesta cuando he visto que ya habías respondido. +1

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar este para monitorear cada que cambia el text field y así habilitar o deshabilitar tus checkboxes:

```
$("input").change(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```